# Using Least Upper Bound Property to prove that $n>r$ for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Given any $r\in\mathbb{R}$, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r<n$. In this exercise, it is suggested to begin with "*Suppose not ... and apply the Least Upper Bound Principle to the set $\mathbb{N}$*". But I don't quite understand what needs to be done there.

Here's what I've tried:

"Suppose that, given any $r\in S\subset \mathbb{R}$, $\not\exists n\in T\subset\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n>r$ (where $S$ and $T$ are bounded subsets). By LUPB, $T$ has a least upper bound, say, $\sup(T) = L$. Then $n\leq L$, $\forall n\in T$. Suppose that $\sup(S)\leq \sup(T)$, then $r \leq n$, a contradiction.

I feel something is not right with my proof. Would appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a proof by contradiction, you should assume the negation of what you're trying to prove, with the goal of arriving at a contradiction. In this case, the negation is "there exists $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $n\leq r$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$."

The existence of such an $r$ implies that the set $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above, hence it has a least upper bound $\alpha$. That is, there exists a real number $\alpha$ such that $n\leq \alpha$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and such that for any $\beta<\alpha$ there exists a natural number $n$ such that $\beta<n$.

Now how can $\beta$ be chosen to lead to a contradiction?

Comment: Choose $\beta := \alpha - \varepsilon$ ($0<\varepsilon < 1$). Then $\beta < \alpha$, but $\alpha - \beta = \alpha - \alpha + \varepsilon = \varepsilon < 1$, which implies $\not\exists n$ such that $\beta < n$. Do you think this argument is good enough? Edit: I think that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ then a contradiction is not reached.

Comment: My idea was to choose $\beta=\alpha-1$. Then there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha-1<n$, hence $\alpha<n+1$. But this is a contradiction because $n+1\in\mathbb{N}$, so $n+1\leq \alpha$.